Creating a title for an HTML page
I've started creating a simple page for an assignment and I'm trying to put a title at the top of the page but whenever I create a paragraph or h1 to do so it's placed next to the divs with the content in the center. I think that the problem has to do with the css code that centers and gives its properties to the body and I doubt it has something to do with the container class.
I've tried to place the title in different places and can't seem to be able to move it to where I want it to be. I've also tried to create a different id for the title so that it's aligned differently.


<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #849edb;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    #container {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 15px;
      width: 15%;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<div>
  <a href='index.html'>
    <img src="casa1.png" alt="" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top: 50px;" />
  </a>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>


<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h2>Sports</h2>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <h2>Informatics</h2>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <h2>Arts</h2>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>

</body>




Try adding flex-direction: column; to your body.

Or / also use a single #container around all your content, instead of wrapping a separate one around each element.  (Among other issues, IDs must be unique within a document).  And that first div belongs inside the body (and probably inside #container)

All elements such as <div> should be inside the body. It's not entirely clear what you mean by "title" though. If you mean the icon and page title that appears in the browsers tab, that's an actual [title] - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Also note that ids should be unique, that is only used once per page, so use a class instead. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLdVejP

I'd also lose the positioning of the logo too. Absolute positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com

It can be useful to put your code through a validator, e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Using this section :-
<div>
    <a href = 'index.html'>
        <img src="casa1.png" alt="" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top: 50px;"/>
    </a>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>

before the <body> tag is not valid HTML.
May be this is what you are trying to do :-


#body {
    background-color: #849edb;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#container {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div>
        <a href='index.html'>
            <img src="casa1.png" alt="" style="position:absolute; left:50px; top: 50px;"/>
        </a>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="container">
            <h2>Sports</h2>
            <p>Text here</p>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <h2>Informatics</h2>
            <p>Text here</p>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <h2>Arts</h2>
            <p>Text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



I have made a body id for all the container and shifted the div class below <body>. If you wish you can easily change background of whole body by the bgcolor Attribute of the body as after making the style for body as an id, those tags without the same id differ in the styling.
<body bgcolor="#849edb">


In my case, it works fine when I change some code position. I put your first div inside the body tag.


body {
  background-color: #849edb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <a href='index.html'>
            <img src="casa1.png" alt=""
                style="position:absolute; left:50px; top: 50px; margin-top100px; width:20px; height:20px;" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Sports</h2>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Informatics</h2>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Arts</h2>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
</body>



Creating a title for an HTML page

The  element in an HTML page specifies the title of the document, which is shown in the browser's title bar or tab. Here's a basic example:


<html>
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your page content goes here -->
</body>
</html>



